# How do I pass javascript variables into a Meteor Spacebars template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Given that I have something like this set in javascript:

```
window.App.url.login = '/account/login';
```

How can I pass that variable into a Meteor Spacebars template?
e.g. something like this:

```
{{> Anchor href=window.App.url.login class="btn-success" label="Login"}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register a global helper for this :

```
Template.registerHelper("appUrlLogin",function(){
  return App.url.login;
});
```

Then use it like this :

```
{{> Anchor href=appUrlLogin class="btn-success" label="Login"}}
```

Alternatively, you could declare the helper on the template directly :

HTML

```
<template name="myTemplate">
  {{> Anchor href=appUrlLogin class="btn-success" label="Login"}}
</template>
```

JS

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  appUrlLogin:function(){
    return App.url.login;
  }
});
```